# SQL Query with multiple lookups

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have encountered a table with five fields refering to a customer list.  The fields (c1, c2, etc..) are id's of the customer in the other table.  Need a SQL statement that will resolve the customer names into a report with on line and the five entires.  Example:

```
Table1
ID  Description   C1   C2   C3
1   PartyGroup     2    3    1
2   BeerFolk       1    0    2

Customer table
ID  Name
1   Rob
2   Joe
3   Fred


Output:
ID  Description  Cust1 Cust2  Cust3
1   PartyGroup   Joe   Fred   Rob
2   BeerFolk     Rob          Joe
```

any thought would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Description, c1.Name AS Cust1, c2.Name AS Cust2, c3.Name AS Cust3
    FROM Table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN Customer c1
            ON t1.C1 = c1.ID
        LEFT JOIN Customer c2
            ON t1.C2 = c2.ID
        LEFT JOIN Customer c3
            ON t1.C3 = c3.ID
```

Comment: I would just revise to prevent "NULL" values for names where the entries are NOT in the c1, c2 and c3 fields respectively.

Comment: @DRapp: Fair enough. Modified as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to multiply reference the customer table in the from clause - alias them as c1, c2, c3 etc - then link normally.

similar to this:

```
select t.id, t.description, c1.name "Cust1", c2.name "Cust2", c3.name "Cuat3"
from table1 t, customer c1, customer c2, customer c3
where t.c1 = c1.id
and t.c2 = c2.id
and t.c3 = c3.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to normalize the table with UNION or UNION ALL:

```
TRANSFORM First(Customer.Name) AS FirstOfName
SELECT Norm.ID, Norm.Description
FROM Customer 
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT ID, Description, "C1" As Cust, C1 As CID 
     FROM table1
     UNION 
     SELECT ID, Description, "C2" As Cust, C2 As CID 
     FROM table1
     UNION 
     SELECT ID, Description, "C3" As Cust, C3 As CID 
     FROM table1) AS Norm 
ON Customer.ID = Norm.CID
GROUP BY Norm.ID, Norm.Description
PIVOT Norm.Cust
```